# Minecraft server Java Jvm arguments

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am trying to make a Minecraft Server but when i do it says the amount of allocated ram is 650 m and i want to allocate more i have 16 gigs of ram installed and i want to allocate 7 or 4 gigs of ram to it but when i try to make the command it says either invalid max heap size the specified size exceeds the max representable size Error: Could not create the java virtual machine Error: A fatal exception has occured. program will exit. i tried making the java option and editing the path but it wont work. i need a list of viable solutions

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Make sure you have a 64-bit JVM to address more memory run `java --version` to check.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did set Xmx and Xms.
You need to set Xmx for max RAM bump up Xms to +1GB RAM and set Xmx to be at max 2GB less then your total system RAM.